# Some key combinations do not work with `key-translation-map`

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to use `Win+arrow` in my emacs to move around the windows using `windmove`. Since config is shared between various machines in general part I have

```
(windmove-default-keybindings 'super) ;; ⌘+direction
```

I had the following in my Windows specific part of the emacs config (which executes last) to achieve it :

```
(when (equal window-system 'w32)
    (setq
       w32-pass-lwindow-to-system nil
       w32-lwindow-modifier 'super
       w32-pass-rwindow-to-system nil
       w32-rwindow-modifier 'super
       w32-pass-apps-to-system nil
       w32-apps-modifier 'hyper
       w32-pass-alt-to-system nil
       w32-scroll-lock-modifier nil))

(dolist (direction-symbol '(left right up down))
  (let* ((direction (symbol-name direction-symbol))
         (windmove-command (intern  (concat  "windmove-"  direction)))
         (keypress-numlock-off (concat  "<C-M-S-kp-"  direction ">"))
         (keypress-numlock-on (concat  "<C-M-kp-" direction ">"))
         (super-direction-keypress (concat  "<s-" direction ">")))
    (define-key key-translation-map (kbd  keypress-numlock-off) (kbd super-direction-keypress) )
    (define-key key-translation-map (kbd  keypress-numlock-on) (kbd super-direction-keypress))))
```

there's also Autohotkey script running that translates `Win+arrow` key into a key combination for Emacs:

```
#Right::
IfWinActive ahk_class Emacs
    Send, ^!+{NumpadRight}
return
```

This setup worked perfectly in Emacs 23 and Emacs 24 until I upgraded to Emacs 24.5. It just stopped working. I can't figure out the reason.

When I call `describe-key` for `Win-Up` I get

> <C-M-up> (translated from <C-M-kp-up>) runs the command
>   backward-up-list, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in

This is a wrong translation because `key-translation-map` looks like

```
 (keymap
 (C-M-kp-down .
              [s-down])
 (C-M-S-kp-down .
                [s-down])
 (C-M-kp-up .
            [s-up])
 (C-M-S-kp-up .
              [s-up])
 (C-M-kp-right .
               [s-right])
 (C-M-S-kp-right .
                 [s-right])
 (C-M-kp-left .
              [s-left])
 (C-M-S-kp-left .
                [s-left])
 (double-down-mouse-1 . mouse--down-1-maybe-follows-link)
 (down-mouse-1 . mouse--down-1-maybe-follows-link)
 (24 keymap
     (56 . iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map)))
```

If I use the same config with Emacs 24.4 it works as expected. If I fire up Emacs 24.5.1 it does not. Has something changed so drastically ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess something has changed from version 24.4 to 24.5 that it stopped working. However, after reading http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Translation-Keymaps.html,
 solution that works is to use `input-decode-map` instead of `key-translation-map`.